# How to save the data selected by user in FORM to the .txt file or csv file

Tags: javascript, html

I have a requirement where i need to store the data selected by user into the txt file. How can i do that? My form is in html and javascript.

Comment: You should probably use php for this... But ehmm, what have you tried so far?

Comment: have you tried anythng?? do paste here

Comment: Open txt file, read file and add what you wnt using server side coding

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know how is with php. Any other server side language would work.

The following tutorial has everything you need to know about working with files using php.

http://www.tizag.com/phpT/files.php

1. create file: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/filecreate.php
2. write to file: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/filewrite.php
   be careful here. You need to choose the correct method of writing to the file depending on weather you want to add to what is already in the file or override it. To append see this: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileappend.php